# Know if the cell is being used in any formula

Tags: google-sheets

For example: A spreadsheet with dozens of pages, I need to delete values from certain cells but first I need to know if there is any formula in the complete spreadsheet using cell `A1` or `A2` or `A3` from `Page 1`. Because if there is a reference to them for the calculation, I can't delete the values that are in the cells.

Is there any way to make the spreadsheet show where these three cells are references to some formula?

When we are creating a formula, the cells we are using as reference for the calculation appear in different colors, correct? There is a way to make this reverse system, choose the cell and show where are formulas that use it.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100791/how-to-see-which-formulas-reference-a-given-cell-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`` ` ``**</kbd>

this will turn on/off the formula view

for a large scale search use <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd> like:

[image: 0]